# Error on Intellij Idea when trying to run a kotlin project

Tags: java, kotlin

Im getting this error.
 What I was doing was the code I want to run didnt run rather it showed up the **Edit Configurations**

The error: `Failed to download Amazon Corretto 18.0.2. EventQueue.isDispatchThread()=false Current thread: Thread[ApplicationImpl pooled thread 110,4,main] 2031890033 SystemEventQueueThread: Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main] 1808191328`

This was what I was trying to fix: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmT0a.png) `Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'kotlin.Array'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies`

And it says that the **JDK "corretto-18" is not found on the disk or corrupted**.

Im using: IntelliJ up to date, Java 18

Does anyone has a solution for this issue??

Thanks-